# How do I boot into a uefi usb drive?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

This is odd... I am currently trying to install windows 7 onto a usb install disk but nothing seems to work so far I have tried

1. Unetbooten
2. winUSB (Grub install failed: Does not look like efi device)
3. Manual (Grub install failed: Does not look like efi device)

I think I need to boot into the drive without using grub. But how??? every install method I have come across on the net uses grub!

I have copied the .iso to the drive and set it's flag to boot in gparted now what???

Comment: No promises, but try [Rufus.](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) I've not tried it for creating a Windows USB flash drive, but it seems more reliable about creating EFI-bootable Linux images than most.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to load your iso to the USB stick. It makes USB Bootable of a lof kinds of OSes (include Windows, Linux, and more). I tried to make LiveUSB with a lot of tools, but this tool works perfect.

Comment: I don't have access to windows :(

Comment: what OS do you have?

Comment: I am stuck on Ubuntu